# Setting Date as a prop in Adobe DTM

Tags: tags, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics, web-analytics

I'm trying to use Adobe DTM to pass the date to a prop variable but haven't had much success. The final output should be a prop report in Adobe that'll provide me traffic data for specific dates (5/11/16, 6/15/15 etc). The ultimate goal for setting the dates as a prop is to be able to classify a range of dates based on various business needs.

Could anyone point me in the right direction for getting this done? I am assuming I'll have to add a line of code in the s.code file that'll define s.prop5 = ...

Thanks

Comment: It's pretty easy to push a value to a prop in DTM. You can look for a query string param, js variable, cookie, etc.  You need to provide more details, such as where is the date coming from on your site? At what point are you looking to pop it - on page load? some click event? etc.

Comment: How is this implemented in DTM ? If you chose that standard integration as a "tool" you can add variables globally in the tool configuration in the "Global Variables" panel oder via a page load rule. The date could be a data element (Top Menu->Rules->Little Left Menu->Data Elements). Usually you should not have to manipulate the tracking library directly when you use DTM.

Comment: @CrayonViolent Thanks for both of your responses. We currently have the code config set up as custom in DTM. We are looking to pull the date on page load so I am assuming it'll has to be some sort of js variable. Is there any recommended solution or is more detail needed?

Comment: when you say "pull the date on page load" do you mean the current datestamp according the to the browser, e.g. if i loaded your page right now, you'd want it to pop "2016-09-28" ? Or some other date, e.g. some article published date?

Comment: @CrayonViolent yes, the current datestamp in the "MM-DD-YYYY" format. I think Gigazelle's data element solution is the route I would be going for but need some help on what the exact JS code I'll need to put for the data layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you are just looking to pop something with the current date stamp with "MM-DD-YYYY" format.

As Gigazelle mentioned, you can create a Data Element to return the value, and then reference it for setting your prop.  However, throwing a data layer into the mix may be overkill for you, depending on your needs/limitations.

Data layers are meant for exposing data that DTM can't feasibly/reliably automate on its own via built-in features or hosting an autonomous js snippet.

The only reason you might want to consider having your site push it to a data layer, is if you want to generate the date via server-side coding to ensure the date is generated within the same timezone setting for all visitors.  If you generate it client-side, it will be generated according to the visitor's browser/system settings. Since visitors are from all over the world in different timezones, the data may not be as consistent (even if you add additional code to change the timezone offset, it still may not be 100% based on browser version/security settings, or visitors who alter their browser/system date/timezone settings).

So, if you want to ensure the best accuracy, then I suggest you output the value via server-side code, and put into a data layer. How you do that depends on your server and what language you have at your disposal for your web pages being served up.  Here is a very basic example using PHP:

```
<script>
var dataLayer = {
  currentDate : '<?php echo date('m-d-Y'); ?>'
}
</script>
```

This will have the server generate the date stamp and output a js object called `dataLayer` with a property `currentDate` you can reference. You can create a **Data Element** as **Type** "JS Object" and for **Path**, put `dataLayer.currentDate`, and then reference your **Data Element** elsewhere (see below).

If that's too much trouble for you or if you want to keep it pure client-side/DTM and are okay with the potentially lower consistency...

Within DTM, go to **Rules** > **Data Elements**, and click **Create New Data Element**.

**Name** it "currentDate" (no quotes).

For **Type**, choose "Custom Script", and click **Open Editor**, and add the following:

```
var t=new Date(),d,m,y;
d=t.getDate();
d=d<10?'0'+d:d;
m=t.getMonth()+1;
m=m<10?'0'+m:m;
y=t.getFullYear();
return m+'-'+d+'-'+y;
```

Click **Save and Close** and **Save Data Element**.

Now you can reference the data element to pop `prop5`.  How you do it depends on how you've setup Adobe Analytics within DTM. For example, if you set it up as a tool and only want it to pop on initial page view, you can open your AA tool config, go to the **Global Variables** dropdown, and set `prop5` there.  You reference it as `%currentDate%`

[image]

You can do the same `%currentDate%` syntax in a **Page Load Rule** or other rule or any other place that uses DTM's built-in fields.

Alternatively, if you need to reference it within javascript code (e.g. if you are setting `prop5` within `s.doPlugins` or some other **Custom Script** box, you can reference the data element like this:

`s.prop5 = _satellite.getVar('currentDate');`

Comment: Thanks so much. Server-side approach seem to make the most sense considering the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set a JS variable on your site (such as within a data layer) that outputs the date in the format you wish to collect it in. Something like `var d = Date();`
2. In DTM, go to Rules > Data Elements and create a data element that maps to the JS variable you created on your site
3. If you want prop5 to be defined on every page, click the gear icon and map prop5 to your data element name by using %DataElementName% (whatever you named your data element in step 2, wrapped in percent signs). If you don't want it defined on every page, go to Rules and create a page load rule, event based rule or direct call rule depending on when you want the variable to trigger. Under the Adobe Analytics section of the rule, map prop5 to %DataElementName% .

This will allow you to collect dates as values, which can then be used in classifications.